# Autofac IComponentContext vs ILifetimeScope

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I was passing the IContainer in a service so I read that it is not good to pass this around but instead use it only to the root of the app and pass either IComponentContext or ILifetimeScope . So I am trying to understand which shall I use IComponentContext or ILifetimeScope. Dont understand the difference

Comment: You should not depend on `IComponentContext` or `ILifetimeScope` or `IComponent` if you need such components, you are using dependency injection as a service locator which is an anti-pattern. You can read http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ for more information

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know it is an anti-pattern but for now I cant avoid it.I only need this to fire up Controllers. From that point and on I use Autofac in the constructor of my classes. So can anyone explain please the difference?

Comment: Anyone knows how to use it?

Comment: Could you edit your post to explain why you need it ? I can't understand why you can't simply depends on the component instead of the lifetimescope

Comment: @CyriilDurand Listen I understand and respect what you said that is not correct to use. And I know why. But you have to understand that it is my choice to use it. The question here is not whether I should use it or not but trying to understand the difference. Thanks

Comment: @CyrilDurand Depending on `IComponentContext` or `ILifetimeScope` is totally fine in certain cases. 
https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/09/19/MessageDispatchingwithoutServiceLocation/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[ILifetimeScope](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac/ILifetimeScope.cs) extends IComponentContext. It adds a few methods for beginning new lifetime scopes. If you need to create a new lifetime scope, then take a dependency on `ILifetimeScope`, otherwise I would suggest `IComponentContext`, so that you don't request more functionality than required.

Taking a dependency on either one is *not* an anti-pattern. There is always a boundary between your DI-aware code and the DI-unaware outside world. E.g. Windows has no knowledge about DI, but your code depends on Autofac. On this boundary you need to use `ILifetimeScope` or `IComponentContext` to bridge this gap.
However if you can have your dependencies injected by Autofac instead of retrieved from a `IComponentContext`, then you should since this is the preferred option.

Comment: Thanks. FInally glad that someone answered the question